# Free visual editor for a language that would compile to native windows exe

Tags: ide, rad, visual-editor

I'm looking for a free visual editor for a language that would compile to native windows exe, no runtime.

I'm looking for alternatives to the Delphi suite (so don't give it as an answer), something that would allow me to write Windows GUI applications with ease.

I don't care about the language, as long as it gets the job done, but I would appreciate if your suggestions avoid functional languages. Even better if it abstracts the windowing system with something more simple than the winAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion: [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) scripting...quite small and handy scripting language. Some people have actually developed a full blown application with it.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you download the free visual studio express edition? With it you can develop in c#, visual basic as well as in 'plain' c++

EDIT:

I know c# and visual basic.net use runtimes. But the runtimes are free anyway so it might not be a problem. When developing in .Net it really is rapid development.

When programming in C you can avoid runtimes, although it is tricky to create something which even doesn't require the msvc runtime dll's

R

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but, please, stick to the point of the question. I already am developing in Visual Studio, and I am aware of the implications. I can't have a 75 Mb runtime download to all the computers I'm deploying an application. Free or not free, in terms of time is anything but that. I don't even want to depend on msvc runtimedll's, I am looking for something that is truly native.

Comment: That depends on which version of Windows you target. Windows Vista and Windows 7, for example, already contain all the necessary files for execution .net Framework 2.0-based applications.

Comment: Luvieere, you didn't say you weren't willing to use C++.  If so, I suggest you use Visual C++ with MFC, and staticly link everything.   If you do that, the EXEs will be small (few hunderd K), and there will be no dependencies on any DLLs including MFC or MSVCRT, etc.   That's really the best solution, unless you have a reason for not wanting to use C++.

Answer (score 1):

[Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/) is an open source implementation/remake of native Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

[Bloodshed Dev++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html) has to be one of my favorites for a free editor.

Comment: Please stop using it. It hasn't been updated in a long time. Some reading: http://www.jasonbadams.net/20081218/why-you-shouldnt-use-dev-c/